# Finding a scale matrix of multivariate Cauchy distribution given a border of credible region

Tags: multivariate-analysis, scales, credible-interval, cauchy-distribution

[image: Bivariate distribution with unknown scale parameter (blue $\gamma$), that needs to be chosen such that the red line (representing a border of ) passes through the data point (blue X)]

I want to solve the following problem:

I have a multivariate Cauchy distribution, centered at $\mu$, with unknown scale matrix $\gamma$. Now I receive a data point (blue $x$ in the picture) and my goal is to **adjust the scale of the distribution so that the data point $x$ lies exactly on the edge of $\alpha$-credible region of the distribution** (credible region border is represented by the red dashed line in the picture).

The problem is quite straightforward to solve in 1D as one plugs $\hat{\alpha} := \dfrac{\alpha+1}{2}$ into the quantile function 
$x = \mu + \gamma \tan[\pi(\hat{\alpha} - 1/2)]$ 
and receives $\gamma = \dfrac{|x-\mu|}{\tan(\dfrac{\pi \alpha}{2})}$.

However, in higher dimensions and without the quantile function available, I still cannot figure it out.
 Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: no, it is actually more like a riddle that is giving me a hard time though :)

Comment: Why do you write that the quantile function is "unavailable"? Isn't it just that of a scaled Student t distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom in dimension $d$?

Comment: Well, I have hard time understanding how that exactly works - like how do you capture the dimensionality with classical quantile function?